# Apply settings to all split-viewed documents in 1 go in ViM

Tags: vim

Let's say I'm viewing two documents in vim, split horizontally:

```
# vim -o interesting_file_name.txt boring_file_name.csv
```

Now let's say I want to apply

```
:set nowrap
```

to both documents at once.

How do I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:windo set nowrap
```

Have a look at

```
:help list-repeat
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thx.